# Writing into Excel sheet failed after hosted to AppHarbor. done in C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I Have written 2 methods in C# . one for getting records from excel sheet and one for inserting into excel sheet. both methods works fine when im running in my local system. but when i hosted it to appHarbor.com, getting records succeded but inserting failed.

here is the insert method

```
private bool AddBlessingToExcel(Blessing blessing)
{
    try
    {

        string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Data") + "/WeddingSheets.xls";

        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");

        // always read from the sheet1.

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand("Insert into [Blessings$] (GuestName, GuestLocation, GuestMessage)" + " values ('" + blessing.GuestName + "', '" + blessing.GuestLocation + "', '" + blessing.GuestMessage + "')");

        myConnection.Open();

        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;


        int val = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Close the connection.
        myConnection.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //throw ex;
        return false;
    }
}
```

i dont know what the problem is exactly but my guess is its because of file permissions..can anyone please provide me a solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the "Settings" page of the application, at the top of the page you should see an option named "Enable file system write access", with a checkbox next to it.

That should give your app write access. However, I believe this gets reset every time you build, so you might have to enable it again after a new deployment.

Comment: If that allows general writing to the file system (all directories) that would be a major security problem.  Write access should only be enabled for a dedicated log directory.